# starting mysql and nodejs with docker-compose results in ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to start mysql and nodejs with docker-compose.  I am running nodejs on port 3006 and I want mysql to use the already created database which is called "locations".
When I execute docker-compose , I don't get any errors but at the console I get this output and it gets "stuck " here.

```
2020-12-04T23:19:20.685756Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

If I now try to start visit localhost:3006  I get the message that the site can't be reached and that the connection was reset.

This is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  nodejs:
    build: ./
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs_2
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3006:3006"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=boom
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=locations
      - MYSQL_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
    volumes:
      - /home/stan/Documents/project:/var/lib/mysql
```

app.js:

```
// Require packages and set the port
const express = require('express');
const port = 3006;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const locations_t = require('/home/stan/Documents/project/locations.js');
const app = express();

// Use Node.js body parsing middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
}));

locations_t(app);


// Start the server
const server = app.listen(port, (error) => {
if (error) return console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.10

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm i -g db-migrate

EXPOSE 3006

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

config.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const config = {
    host: 'mysql',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'locations',
};

// Create a MySQL pool
const pool = mysql.createPool(config);
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
// Export the pool
module.exports = pool;
```

locations.js:

```
// Load the MySQL pool connection
const pool = require('/home/stan/Documents/projects/config.js');

const router = app => {
    // Display welcome message on the root
    app.get('/', (request, response) => {
        response.send({
            message: 'Welcome!!'
        });
});
```

If i start app.js without docker-compose everything works fine but starting it with docker localhost can not be reached.
Could someone help me out?
I have been stuck on the issue for days.

Comment: The `CMD` in your image doesn't actually start the application; try changing it to something like `CMD npm run start`.  You also need to make sure to `COPY` the application code into the image, not just the `package.json` file.

Comment: So i need to copy config.json, locations.json and app.json  in the dockerfile?